# Increasing minimum Android SDK for app update on play store. Can users with less than min SDK still download the previous version from store?

Tags: android, google-play

Let me give an example.

App version 1.0:
Minimum SDK is 17+

App version 1.1:
Minimum SDK 21+

So John with a device **SDK 18** can't get the latest version (1.1).
But if he goes to play store with the app link, can he still download the previously supported version (1.0) or not?

If I have updated as usual on Play store, the old version won't be available to old SDK users right? I only want the latest version available. If older device view it, no longer supported is what we need.

Just want to know how Play store handles this situation. Thanks.

Comment: You can set it up that way, yes.  Although I really wouldn't worry too much-  less than 1.5% of the world uses devices that old, according to Google's own statistics.  And if your target market is America or the Western world in general it shrinks to a tiny fraction of that (most devices that old are in smaller, poorer countries).

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks, I don't want to set it up that way. All I want to know, if I have updated as usual, the old version won't be available to old SDK users right? I only want the latest version available.  If older device, no longer available.